# Validación de fechas en php con js

Tags: php, javascript

una pregunta, requiero hacer un formulario de registro acerca de votaciones, mi problema es que si el usuario es hombre tendrá que pasar 3 meses antes de votar nuevamente y es mujer tenga que pasar 4 meses, sabrán como puedo hacer esa validación?

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y casi que basada en opiniones lo cual generará su cierre, lee [ask]

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir lo que has hecho hasta el momento? Recuerda que agregar un [ejemplo mínimo repoducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) es de mucha ayuda para que otros puedan ayudarte y/o aclarar tus dudas.